# jQuery validation not performing correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am checking whether someone has selected a property type (house/flat) and then checking the sub list of either houses or flats to see whether they have selected a sub-type of there selected property (ie. house -> semi-detached etc.)

The house validation is working fine, the flats validation isn't however even though their syntax is the same, I feel like I'm missing something really obvious here.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dyates88/vCmnW/iddle

jQuery:

```
valid = true;

    if (index === 2) {

        if (!$("#htype div").hasClass("selected")) {
            alert("Please select a Property type!");
            valid = false;

        } else if ($("#htype div").attr('sel') == 'true' && $("#htype div").attr('id') == 'flat' && !$("#flats div").hasClass("selected")) {


            alert("Please Select a flat type!");
            valid = false;



        } else if ($("#htype div").attr('sel') == 'true' && $("#htype div").attr('id') == 'house' && !$("#houses div").hasClass("selected")) {


            alert("Please Select a house type!");
            valid = false;

        }
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: yeah try adding a fiddle so we can see how you created your elements. the code seems to be incomplete.

Comment: please add a html part of code sp we can assist you well

Comment: i can add the html but adding anymore would be difficult as its part of a larger system :(

Comment: Because you used an `else if` block which is preventing the statement to be executed if the previous one `true`. You need to put your last satement in a seperate `if` block

Comment: i have added a fiddle!